# How to combine two commands as a launcher?

Tags: command-line

I want to combine these two commands:

```
rvm use 1.9.2
```

and

```
redcar
```

and combine them to run as a standalone program. But when i created a launcher with these two commands inputted, separated by semicolon, it just doesn't work.

How to implement this function?

Comment: Why don't you accept an answer?

Answer (score 15):

```
sh -c "command 1 ; command 2"
```

did the job for me, directly as a launcher:
just create a file and save it as  program.desktop, then allow execution as a program (right click -> properties-> permissions -> allow executing as program)

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=ProgramName
Comment=This is my comment
Exec=sh -c "command 1 ; command 2"
Icon=/home/alex/Pictures/icon.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;
```

Comment: Yay! Your technique also works in the Alt+F2 launcher dialog. It would normally only execute at most one command, at least in LXDE. Now, sth. like `sh -c "xeyes & xeyes"` works.

Comment: Great! This also works for assigning multiple commands to a custom keyboard shortcut in 16.04 (for some reason, simply writing "command 1 ; command 2" doesn't work).

Answer (score 2):

```
rvm use 1.9.2 && redcar
```

or

```
rvm use 1.9.2 || redcar
```

if the rvm-command fails, redcar is excecuted in the second example and not in the first example.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure Gnome launcher supports this, but in a bash script a command like

```
program1; program2
```

means - start program1, then start program2 only after the first one terminates.

After some testing I think the most robust thing would be to create a simple script:

```
#!/bin/sh
rvm use 1.9.2 &
redcar &
```

set the executable bit on it and then create a launcher which starts *this script*, i.e. /home/yourusername/start_redcar.sh

As a bonus - if you create a directory called "bin" in your home folder, put the script there and name it "start_redcar", you'll be able to start it from terminal or from the "Run a command" window which opens when pressing Alt-F2 - by simply typing the command name

Answer (score 2):

To use a command line program (`tiff2pdf`) I wanted a terminal with the program help, then an additional note about a related program (`tiffcp`), then a command prompt so I could use the program in the same terminal. I made an entry in the Gnome laucher of type Application (NOT Application in terminal!):

```
gnome-terminal -x bash -c "tiff2pdf -h; echo '** See also tiffcp'; exec bash"
```