# How to black out a region of one virtual desktop?

Tags: command-line, annotation

I am looking for a command-line solution to cover a configurable section of a virtual desktop with a rectangle of configurable color, to hide the content below. One should still be able to use a window which has part of its content hidden this way.

A screen annotation tool (as discussed in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/328543)) does not work here because the overlay painting will affect all virtual desktops at the same time, at least in all the tools I tested.

(The application for this is covering nasty banner ads in a non-browser application. It might also be used to [hide content in a live presentation](https://superuser.com/q/916424).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `feh` image viewer to diplay a transparent image on black or white background in your defined size and position and without window decorations. And then use the `wmctrl` command to make it stay on top of all other windows, as shown in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/180797).

So an example command (here to hide Spotify visual ads on a 1280x800 screen) looks like this:

```
sh -c "feh --borderless --title hidemyads --geometry 980x95+302+643 \
    --image-bg black /path/to/transparent.png & \
  sleep 0.3 && \
  wmctrl -r hidemyads -b add,above"
```

Annotations and explanations:

- To find out the geometry to use, position and resize any window where you want it, and find out its geometry from `wmctrl -lG` output.
- `wmctrl -r` selects the window where the title matches the supplied string, so we make that string unique by setting the window title in `feh` before.
- We need to [sleep a bit](https://serverfault.com/q/469247) after `feh`, as there seems to be a short delay until the window manager knows about the new window. Usually 0.1 s is enough, but depending on system load etc. more might be required, so we triple it.
- `feh` does not yet support configuring the image background color beyond `--image-bg black` and `--image-bg white`, but if you really want, [a patch is available](https://github.com/derf/feh/issues/125).
- To configure the color, you can of course use an image in that color. But it's not flexible: `feh` always shows the image in original aspect ratio, so you would have to adapt the image aspect ratio to what you want to use in `--geometry`.
- The wrapping in `sh -c "…"` follows [this technique](https://askubuntu.com/a/527717) to make the command also execute in the Alt+F2 launcher (which would otherwise only execute one, at least in LXDE). Also, the wrapping detaches the command from a terminal (so that the `feh` window stays open when closing the terminal window).